# How to sort multi valued list in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have list with below values

```
[
[Invoice Number:452170, Date:12-05-2016, Price:124589.0, Customer Name:David Copperfield], 
[Invoice Number:452171, Date:13-04-2014, Price:453212.0, Customer Name:David Bowie], 
[Invoice Number:452172, Date:24-07-2013, Price:21458.0, Customer Name:David Beckham], 
[Invoice Number:452173, Date:21-05-2017, Price:47852.0, Customer Name:David Koresh]
]
```

I would like to sort this list descending order of price and then by the customer name in alphabetical order in groovy.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow. To make your questions easier to answer please look into the formatting options the next time: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Also try to provide valid code. For example instead of ` [Invoice Number:452170]` use ` ["Invoice Number":452170]` the next time. This allows to easily paste your code in an editor and verify the answer. Those things make it easier to read and answer your question and you'll get faster and better answers ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a custom sort order by passing a closure to the `sort` method as described here: [TO THE NEW - Groovier way of sorting over multiple fields in a list of maps in groovy](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/groovier-way-of-sorting-over-multiple-fields-in-a-list-of-maps-in-groovy/)

```
list.sort { a,b ->
   a.price <=> b.price ?: a.lastName <=> b.lastName
}
```

The "spaceship operator" (`<=>`) calls the `compareTo` method which is used for sorting. It returns 0 when both compared items are equal. This is where the elvis operator (`?:`) comes in: it evaluates the expression before it as `boolean` (according to groovy truthyness) and returns it's value if it is `true`. Since 0 evaluates to false, the expression behind the elvis operator is returned.

So if the price is not equal (`a.price <=> b.price` is not 0) the result of `a.price <=> b.price` is used for sorting. But if they are equal `a.lastName <=> b.lastName` is used for sorting.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked but price sorted in ascending order, how to sort price in descending order. Thank you.

Comment: switch places: `b.price <=> a.price`

Comment: Thanks again, but still couldn't get the expected sorting. (sort list descending order of price and then by the customer name in alphabet order). Expected sorted order Inv Num: 452171 | Dt:13-04-2014 | Price:453212.0 | Customer Name:David Bowie
Inv Number:452170 | Dt:12-05-2016 | Price:124589.0 | Customer Name:David Copperfield
Inv Num: 452173 | Dt: 21-05-2017 | Price : 47852.0 | Customer Name : David Koresh
Inv Num: 452172 | Dt: 24-07-2013 | Price : 21458.0 | Customer Name : David Beckham  code:  l.sort { a,b ->
    b.'Price' <=> a.'Price' ?: a.'Customer Name' <=> b.'Customer Name'
    }

Comment: Are the prices of a number type? Make sure they are no Strings

Comment: While adding the value I am parsing it to double. How to validate the data type of price?

Answer (score 1):

What if you do straightforward sort?

```
invoices.sort { a, b ->
    if (a.Price > b.Price) return -1
    if (a.Price < b.Price) return 1
    else
        return (a.'Customer Name' > b.'CustomerName') ? -1 : 1
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Above sorts either based on price or name.